# Assign into a grid of a NumPy array given row and column indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to access a specific row and column restriction of a 2d numpy array.

```
> x
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

If I do what seems natural, I just get the diagonal elements of the restricted array.

```
> x[[0,1], [0,1]]
array([1, 4])
```

Instead I can do this to read what I want -

```
> x[[0,1],:][:,[0,1]]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

..but it doesn't let me write/assign the values.

```
> x[[0,1],:][:,[0,1]] = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])

> x 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

How can I write to a matrix here?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to map that grid of elements and then assign -

```
x[np.ix_([0,1], [0,1])] = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
x[:2, :2] = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
```